# Multiple Dates Select in datepicker

Tags: javascript, html-table, datepicker

I am Using Multi Datepicker to select multiple dates at once. When user click on a date than it would be added into a table row dynamically, and if user click again on same date than it would be remove from table row. Below is my code for that, Can anyone please tell me where I am wrong?

```js
var arr = [];
$('#multiple-date-select').multiDatesPicker({
  onSelect: function(datetext) {
    if (arr.includes(datetext)) {
      var table = document.getElementById('table-data');
      var data = document.getElementById('newrow');
      data.removeChild(td);
    } else {
      var table = document.getElementById('table-data');
      var row = document.createElement('tr');
      var col = document.createElement('td');
      row.setAttribute('id', 'newrow');
      col.innerHTML = datetext;
      row.appendChild(col);
      table.appendChild(row);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<form name="select-multiple">
  <input id="multiple-date-select" />
</form>
<table id="table-data" border="1"></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    var arr = [];
    $('#multiple-date-select').multiDatesPicker({onSelect:function(datetext){

        if(arr.includes(datetext)){
            var table = document.getElementById('table-data');
            var data = document.getElementById(datetext);
            data.remove(); 
            arr.splice(datetext,1)
        }else{
            arr.push(datetext)
            var table = document.getElementById('table-data');
            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            var col = document.createElement('td');
            row.setAttribute('id',datetext);
            col.innerHTML = datetext;
            row.appendChild(col);
            table.appendChild(row);         
        }   
    }});        
 </script>
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to this answer, e.g. what each part does

Comment: Be aware that this is only HTML5 so if you have to support browsers that are not HTML5 compatible this may not work or may have issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should set some unique ID for each new `tr` created and remove by selected that ID. I've updated script:

```
<script>
    var arr = [];
    $('#multiple-date-select').multiDatesPicker({onSelect: function (datetext) {
            var index = arr.indexOf(datetext),
                    table = document.getElementById('table-data');
            if (index > -1) {
                document.getElementById(datetext).remove();
                arr.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                var row = document.createElement('tr'),
                        col = document.createElement('td');
                row.setAttribute('id', datetext);
                col.innerHTML = datetext;
                row.appendChild(col);
                table.appendChild(row);
                arr.push(datetext);
            }
        }});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Be aware that this is only HTML5 so if you have to support browsers that are not HTML5 compatible this may not work or may have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping both an array and a set of table rows in sync.  You need unique row ids on the rows, so we need to use some if you DO want id's on them.

You need to add/remove both the rows in the table and the array elements.  You had jQuery already so I used that to manage the rows and put data on those rows.

Now to keep a unique id, we use a data property on the table to keep track of the last one we added, increment it as rows are added, id will always be unique.

NOTE: I would be very cautious of using slashes in the id property (using the date text as that id) as you may run into issues selecting or managing that later.  I avoid that with this solution.

```js
var arr = [];

function removeRow(r) {
  var index = arr.indexOf(r);
  if (index > -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
$('#multiple-date-select').multiDatesPicker({
  onSelect: function(datetext) {
    let table = $('#table-data');
    let rowLast = table.data('lastrow');
    let rowNext = rowLast + 1;
    let r = table.find('tr').filter(function() {
      return ($(this).data('date') == datetext);
    }).eq(0);
    // a little redundant checking both here 
    if (!!r.length && arr.includes(datetext)) {
      removeRow(datetext);
      r.remove();
    } else {
      // not found so add it
      let col = $('<td></td>').html(datetext);
      let row = $('<tr></tr>');
      row.data('date', datetext);
      row.attr('id', 'newrow' + rowNext);
      row.append(col).appendTo(table);
      table.data('lastrow', rowNext);
      arr.push(datetext);
    }
  }
});
// set start, first row will be 0 could be in markup
$('#table-data').data('lastrow', -1);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<form name="select-multiple">
  <input id="multiple-date-select" />
</form>
<table id="table-data" border="1"></table>
```